# AWS unable to connect with data in query editor using secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

I've been trying to access my AWS RDS database with my secrets manager, whenever I try to access the query editor it shows me connect to the database dialog, from there I select "Connect with Secret Manager ARN", after that I paste my secret manager ARN and click on connect!

every time it comes to an end with this error: Connection failed, please double check your database username, password, and assure the database is available.
[image]

The secret manager ARN I use is created using the option "Credentials for RDS connection" and the appropriate database is selected, what else should I do to have access to the database using secrets manager.
[image]

Note:
The data API is already enabled and I can successfully connect with database credentials but not with the secret manager ARN.

Comment: Solved. I made a mistake during the creation of secrets, I needed to use the credentials in the secret that I used when creating a serverless rds instance.